# perfectScrollbar and mCustomScrollbar combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I am trying to use two plugins together.

1) http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

2) https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

I have the following code

```
require('perfect-scrollbar/jquery');

$(".slide_three").perfectScrollbar();
$(".slide_three").mCustomScrollbar();
```

But it gives me an error:

```
app.js:3955 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function
    at Object.30.perfect-scrollbar/jquery (app.js:3955)
    at s (app.js:1)
    at e (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
```

So, the question is - how can I combine these two plugins, or is there a plugin to have smooth scrolling options and style options for scroll bar at one plugin?

Comment: Why not just run with plain jQuery? Or even raw JavaScript? What specific behaviour are you trying to obtain by combining these two plugins?

Comment: @ObsidianAge First of all, to change the style of the scroll bar, and then change the speed of the scrolling. make it smoothier.

Comment: Ehh, personally I don't understand why people keep creating plugins to change this sort of thing. [**PerfectScrollbar**](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) doesn't even support auto-scrolling with the mousewheel (which makes me question the name). I'd recommend not using it. That would, coincidentally, also completely solve your conflict problem.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Everything is good now, I have changed both of them on 'smooth-scrollbar'